# LuaCOM Word Document Header

Tags: com, lua, luacom

I'm trying to do some LuaCOM programming creating word documents. I've figured out most of it, but can't seem to understand how the headers/footers work.

```
word = luacom.CreateObject("Word.Application")


book = word.documents:Add()
word.Visible = true



paras = book.Paragraphs:Add()
range = paras.Range

range.Text = ([[Nam fabulas mnesarchum comprehensam ne, cu ullum euismod consulatu usu. Eam alii lobortis voluptatum id, denique eligendi pertinax quo ne. Vis congue eirmod ut. Duo probo soleat ex. Elit pertinax abhorreant eu his, ipsum dicam dissentiunt pri id. Kasd erant dolorum id sed, ei vim partem deseruisse, ne mea dico tantas alienum.
Has cu facilisis mediocritatem. Fabellas lucilius vim ex.
]])

book.InlineShapes:AddPicture("C:\\13.png", 0, 1);
range.Style = ("Normal")
range:InsertParagraphAfter()

word.DisplayAlerts = false;

doc = nil
word = nil
```

Here I'm just creating a standard document with a paragraph, and adding an image near the top. I'd like to have the image in the header along with some text centered in the header.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: *Confession Bear* : I upvoted because I just found LuaCOM exists.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```lua
require("luacom")
local word = luacom.CreateObject("Word.Application")
local book = word.documents:Add()
word.Visible = true
local section = book.Sections(1)
local headers = section.Headers
local header = headers:Item(1)
header.Range.Text = "HEADER"
header.Range.InlineShapes:AddPicture("C:\\13.png", 0, 1);
doc = nil
word = nil
```